# Duration of a generated audio sine wave

Tags: android, audio

I am trying to generate 5 seconds of sine wave sound with frequency 1000.
I have written the following code

```
int sampleRate = 44100;
int freqOfTone = 1000;
AudioTrack track;
// 5 seconds
short samples = new short[sampleRate*5];
track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
         sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                                      AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, samples.length,
                                      AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);

double angle = 0;
double increment = (2 * Math.PI * freqOfTone / sampleRate); // angular increment 

for (int i = 0; i < samples.length-1; i++) {
          samples[i] =   (short) (Math.sin(angle) * Short.MAX_VALUE);
          angle += increment;
    }
track.write(samples, 0, samples.length); // write data to audio hardware 
track.play();
```

The sound wave length is only 2.5 seconds and I think it should be 5 seconds. Why?

Answer (score 2):

See the reference.

The 5th argument of AudioTrack constructor is "bufferSizeInBytes".

Comment: This is the answer, change the fifth argument from `samples.length` to `samples.length * Short.SIZE / Byte.SIZE`.

Answer (score 0):

Is `track.play();` synchronous or asynchronous? If the latter, you may be ending the program and shutting it down before it gets a chance to finish. You can try a "press any key" or other pause at the end to confirm.

Comment: I am using the static mode not the stream mode. Also, I tried it inside a button and I still have the same problem. If I put the samples 10*sampleRate, I get 5 seconds. So it is always divided by 2.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the correct behavior because you specified a `ENCODING_PCM_16BIT`, if you change it to `ENCODING_PCM_8BIT` you will get 5 seconds of play.

Comment: But I am storing the samples in 16-bit register (short) not in 8-bit (byte). Anyway, I need to stay on Encoding_PCM_16BIT, how can I get 5 seconds?

Comment: You already know the answer, multiply `sampleRate` by 10 instead of 5

Comment: That's the question; Why should I multiply by 2. Also, when I did that (sampleRate*10), the frequency of the sound will be 2000hz instead of 1000hz. I need it to be 5sec with 1000hz.

Comment: This doesn't make sense, assume you wanted to generate 10 seconds with frequency 1000. Using your code it was going to be `1000 * 10` which exactly equal to `2000 * 5` so is it 5 seconds with frequency 2000 or 10 seconds with frequency 1000 !?

Comment: As a conclusion. What should the numberofsamples be to have 5 sec, 1000 hz, 16bit_encoding? You can try the code quickly.